# animation not work in IE when jQuery ajax calling inside js function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, animation, webmethod

I'm trying to show a div with gif animation inside when a button click via javascript call. But the problem is, it's working fine in firefox only. In IE and Chrome, the animation won't show up. I've tried debugging with alert("stop"); before and after the animation and it's indeed working, but after I removed the alert, it won't work anymore. Any suggestion please?

Here's the snippet for the TestPage.aspx:

```
<div id="animationDiv" style="display: none;">
    <img src="loading.gif" />
</div>
...
<div>
    <asp:Button ID="testButton" runat="server" Text="Test AJAX" OnClientClick="return testButtonClick();" />
</div>
...
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
    var docWidth, docHeight;

    function testButtonClick() {
        var o_animationDiv = $("#animationDiv");

        o_animationDiv.width(docWidth);
        o_animationDiv.height(docHeight);
        o_animationDiv.show();

        $.ajax({
            type: "Post",
            url: "TestPage.aspx/TestAjax",
            async: false,
            cache: false,
            data: "{}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: testAjaxSuccess,
            error: testAjaxError
        });

        function testAjaxSuccess(data, status, xhr) {
            // do something here
        };

        function testAjaxError(xhr, status, error) {
            // do something here
        };

        o_animationDiv.hide();

        return false;
    };

    $(document).ready(function () {
        docWidth = $(document).width();
        docHeight = $(document).height();
    });
//-->
</script>
```

Here's the snippet for TestPage.aspx.cs:

```
// using PageMethod for ajax
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public static string TestAjax()
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000); // 5 seconds

    // or do something else here
    // ie. if validation error, throw an exception

    return string.Empty;
}
```

UPDATE 1: added some javascript function

Comment: I am facing the same problem, if you get the solution, then help me to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery ajax is **asynchronous**, so that won't wait for ajax result to hide again.

```
 o_animationDiv.hide();
 o_animationDiv.show();
```

This lines work in serial and you can't see if it's working properly. So you should wait for ajax result to hide it.Try this,

```
  $.ajax({
            type: "Post",
            url: "TestPage.aspx/TestAjax",
            async: false,
            cache: false,
            data: "{}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json"
        }).done(function() {
            o_animationDiv.hide();
        });
```

## UPDATE:

Sorry I missed the point that you create a synchronous ajax request.
But there is a problem already. Most browsers lock itself when running a synchronous XHR. This also effects previous proccess sometimes.

- [Here is a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11013666/animation-not-work-in-ie-when-jquery-ajax-calling-inside-js-function/11013796#11013796)

Maybe if you use `beforeSend`, you can avoid this problem.

***beforeSend***

```
 A pre-request callback function that can be used to modify the jqXHR 
(in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHTTPRequest) object before it is sent
```

Try this one,

```
$.ajax({
            type: "Post",
            url: "TestPage.aspx/TestAjax",
            async: false,
            cache: false,
            data: "{}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            beforeSend : function() {
               o_animationDiv.show();
            }
        }).done(function() {
            o_animationDiv.hide();
        });
```

## UPDATE-2:

If that doesn't work, try this one,

```
...
o_animationDiv.width(docWidth);
o_animationDiv.height(docHeight);
o_animationDiv.show();

setTimeout(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "Post",
            url: "TestPage.aspx/TestAjax",
            async: false,
            cache: false,
            data: "{}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: testAjaxSuccess,
            error: testAjaxError
        }).done(function() {
            o_animationDiv.hide();
        });
}, 600);
```

Comment: CMIIW. It's synchronous calling because I set it in $.ajax function async: false. So, it should be wait the ajax first before executing the next line.

Comment: @Roby, yes, I didn't see that you set false async. Look my updated answer again.

Comment: :-( it's still not working. I've added the "beforeSend" and "done" part but the div still not show up.

Comment: [here is similar problem you have](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11013666/animation-not-work-in-ie-when-jquery-ajax-calling-inside-js-function/11013796#11013796). But I have a diffrent solution for this, can you try to put your ajax process in a timeout function- > `setTimeout(function() {/*your ajax process*/}, 600)`;

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you call the `.hide()` on the post success:

```
$.ajax({
  type  : "Post",
  url   : "TestPage.aspx/TestAjax",
  cache : false,
  data  : "{}",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(data) {

    // hide element when POST return as arrived,
    // meaning the "5 seconds" period has ended!
    o_animationDiv.hide();

  }
});
```

You can read about callback function at the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#callback-functions)!

Comment: I've tried it with similar function to those lines and it's still not working. The one I tried: success: TestAjaxSuccess, error: TestAjaxError. Both TestAjaxSuccess and TestAjaxError is a function.

Comment: Your post is going to do what precisely? Just wait x seconds and return nothing? Or some actual interaction will be happening there?

Comment: Actually, there will be one to three ajax calling inside a button click function, depending on which button is being clicked. For example if a save button is clicked, then it suppose to do this in sequence: calling save pagemethod (in here the input being validated and if it's success it will be saved), if success, change the button state (ie. disabled the button) and load the saved data, if error, show the error message returned from the server.